# Google Maps API Current location not working. (Swift 3, IOS10, Xcode 8.2)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I cant seem to get the current location of the user (device) when using my **UIViewController** as a **root controller** of a **Navigation Controller**.

I am able to display the current location of the user when I am not using the UIViewController as a root of the Navigation Controller

It just show a random place. Please help!

Comment: And how ViewController is displayed, if it isn't root view controller of Navigation Controller?

Comment: @Sander I found the problem and it's because of the segue. Going from Login to the navigation controller using a segue, the current location of the user is not shown. If directly to the view controller it works.